# Ruby on Rails, nested resource, use url id on submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have:

/projects/1/steps/new

When I submit a step, how do I save the project_id in step?

Do I need a hidden form field with "project_id", or can I set some other way?

As of now when submitted project_id get sets to nil

Comment: Can you show your view? How do you build your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are building the form as follows, to maintain the nested routing:

```
form_for [@project, @step]
```

Then, inside your `StepsController` you will receive a parameter `:project_id`.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can write in your controller create action:

```
@project.find params[:project_id]
@project.build params[:step]
```

In that case you don't need to pass hidden field.

Comment: If I'm submitting to steps controller not project controller, then I guess there isn't a way to do this?